# INSERT en tabla el ID de session user

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo los datos de inicio de sesion y tomo el id de usuario para usar luego

```
session_start();
$usuario= $_SESSION["login_user"]["user"];
$id_cliente= $_SESSION["login_user"]["id_cliente"];
```

Tengo como objetivo añadir estos datos en mi base de datos. Esto es lo esperable

| id_registro | id_cliente | monto | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 00352 | 20 | 11/1/2022 |
| 000002 | 00025 | 35 | 11/1/2022 |

El monto lo tomo de un input.  Todo bien hasta aquí.

```
$monto=$_POST['monto'];
```

Quisiera utilizar el **$id_cliente** del usuario para hacer un INSERT

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla(id_registro, id_cliente, monto, fecha) value ('$id_cliente','$monto','$fecha')"
```

Pero al momento de realizarse el registro, no me guarda el id del usuario y se realiza en INSERT de la siguiente forma

| id_registro | id_cliente | monto | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 00000 | 20 | 11/1/2022 |
| 000002 | 00000 | 35 | 11/1/2022 |

Quisiera tomar el **id_cliente** del usuario y usarlo en el mismo archivo para realizar registros.

> Nota: El id al que hago referencia, es un id secundario del usuario. Cada usuario tiene un "id_usuario" y un "id_cliente" para cumplir con las necesidades del sitio web. Pero para este caso en especifico, necesito utilizar solamente el "id_cliente" para el INSERT. Agradezco cualquier aporte.

Comment: Cuando algo funcione mal, haz una depuración. En este caso, verifica lo que hay en tu variable de sesión con algo como esto: **`var_dump($_SESSION["login_user"]);`** y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano. Me muestra NULL.

Comment: En cambio si uso $id_cliente = $row['id_cliente']; si me trae el id correctamente, pero al momento de hacer el insert me sigue guardando el valor 00000.

Comment: Entonces revisa tu variable de sesión completa con **`var_dump($_SESSION);`** no sea que los datos se estén guardando de otro modo. Si no muestra nada, entonces verifica el código donde se supone que se guardan los datos en la variable de sesión.

Answer (score 0):

Quite la comillas de la consulta en la variable `id_cliente`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla(id_registro, id_cliente, monto, fecha) value ($id_cliente,'$monto','$fecha')";
```